# How to calculate the similarity between two Redis sorted sets?

Tags: redis, similarity, sortedset

I have an application which keeps a redis sorted set of each user's browsing history for a particular type of resource.

Each user has a set containing the ids of resources they've viewed, scored by the number of times they've viewed the resource.

I'm wondering if there is a practical way to work out the sets which are "nearest" or "most similar" to the current user's set. (So that I can use the sets to make content recommendations.)

Comment: I guess your looking for something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26698644/1925997

Comment: Possibly, but it's not clear to me how diffing the sets would let me determine and rank similarity between numerous zsets. Also hoping for a measure of similarity which encompasses similarity in rank as well as just set contents, which I have a feeling the diff route wouldn't allow, also (?).