# In Redis how to separate records from 1st set by excluding records from 2nd sorted sets.?

Tags: redis, sortedset, set-difference

I have two sorted sets, I want to separate records from 1st set and store in new list/sorted set by excluding records from 2nd sorted sets.

Below is an example:

set1: 1,2,3,4,5 
set2: 3,5,7,8,9

output: 1,2,4

**EDIT:** I have figured out the way to load the script and use eval to execute script from nodejs.

Strange is when I executed your script even for 5-10 records it taking 1 second to process, which making me doubtful how much scalable it is if I have thousands of records.

Below is my sample nodejs code:

```
hsetxx = 'redis.call("ZINTERSTORE","temp",2,"set11","set21","weights",1,0) redis.call("ZUNIONSTORE","result",2,"set11","temp","weights",1,-1) redis.call("ZREMRANGEBYSCORE","result",0,0)';

var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient('14470', connection);

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected to Redis');
});

client.script('load',hsetxx,function(err, result) {
     console.log(err+'------------'+result);
 });

client.zadd('set11', 1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5);
client.zadd('set21', 1,1,1,5);

client.evalsha(
 '39c0da298cab6a6223b4d1e8222cf6d6a84e67b1', //lua source 
 0,
 function(err, result) {
     client.zrange('result', 0, -1, function(err, result) {
          console.log(err+'------------'+result);
      });
 }
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DIFF on sorted set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698179/how-to-get-diff-on-sorted-set)

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698179/how-to-get-diff-on-sorted-set) question:

> What you could do is first create a temporary set with ZUNIONSTORE and
>   set the intersect's scores to 0. Then do a range excluding the 0,
>   e.g.:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD all 1 one 2 two 3 three
> (integer) 3
> 127.0.0.1:6379> SADD disabled two
> (integer) 1
> 127.0.0.1:6379> ZUNIONSTORE tmp 2 all disabled WEIGHTS 1 0 AGGREGATE MIN
> (integer) 3
> 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGEBYSCORE tmp +inf 1 WITHSCORES
> 1) "three"
> 2) "3"
> 3) "one"
> 4) "1"
> ```

Comment: Following workaround works for me:                                                    ZADD key1 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 
ZADD key2 1 1 1 5 

ZINTERSTORE temp 2 key1 key2 weights 1 0 
ZUNIONSTORE result 2 key1 temp weights 1 -1 
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE result 0 0 
DEL temp 

ZRANGE result 0 -1
1) "2"
2) "3"
3) "4"  DO YOU THINK ANY PERFORMANCE ISSUE?

Comment: Ha  - that's also mine :) it would be interesting to compare this with the Lua script

Answer (score 1):

it was great having the discussion earlier. As promised, another approach to address the challenge is with Lua and Redis' [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval). I don't know how performant it will be but here's a (not too tested) script that mimics `SDIFF` but for Sorted Sets:

```
~/src/redis-lua-scripts$ cat zdiff.lua 
-- ZDIFF key [key ...]
-- Returns the elements in the first key that are also present in all other keys

local key = table.remove(KEYS,1)
local elems = redis.call('ZRANGE', key, 0, -1)
local reply = {}

if #KEYS > 0 and #elems > 0 then
  for i, e in ipairs(elems) do
    local exists = true
    for j, k in ipairs(KEYS) do
      local score = redis.call('ZSCORE', k, e)
      if not score then
        exists = false
        break
      end
    end
    if exists then
      reply[#reply+1] = e
    end
  end
end

return reply
~/src/redis-lua-scripts$ redis-cli SCRIPT LOAD "`cat zdiff.lua`"
"e25d895f05dc638be87d13aed64e8d5780f17c99"
~/src/redis-lua-scripts$ redis-cli ZADD zset1 0 a 0 b 0 c 0 d 0 e
(integer) 5
~/src/redis-lua-scripts$ redis-cli ZADD zset2 0 a
(integer) 1
~/src/redis-lua-scripts$ redis-cli ZADD zset3 0 a 0 b
(integer) 2
~/src/redis-lua-scripts$ redis-cli EVALSHA e25d895f05dc638be87d13aed64e8d5780f17c99 3 zset1 zset2 zset3
1) "a"
```

Comment: As I am new to Redis and lua scripts, hard time for me to understand 

- how I can deploy my lua scripts on redislabs hosted redis db. 
- Call lua script from my node application

Any reference or steps can help me lot.

JFYI: I am using free edition of redislabs for now, as I am still evaluating it.

Comment: can you please give me script to exclude records of set1 which are exists in set2? Also what we have millions of records. will it cause performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for SDIFF:

```
key1 = {a,b,c,d}
key2 = {c}
key3 = {a,c,e}
SDIFF key1 key2 key3 = {b,d}
```

https://redis.io/commands/sdiff

However, there is no equivalent for sorted sets.

Comment: No, I want to use sorted sets. I couldnt find ZDIFF for it, any workaround?

Comment: You can write it in Lua or implement it as a module.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer could you elaborate on that? Why Lua? A module of what?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli There are two ways to add functionality to redis - Lua scripts that run inside the server, or modules written in C that can extend it. Both can implement the functionality of ZDIFF. In fact, I don't mind quickly writing a module that does ZDIFF just to demonstrate it. Lua will be much slower, but both will work.